# Weird Emacs highlighting problem

Tags: emacs

Hi I'm new to emacs on the mac and i mistakenly pressed a couple of wrong buttons that caused some lines of text to highlight pink (see below).

Is there a way i can get rid of this highlighting? What exactly is it?

[image]

Comment: Does saving, closing and reopening the file helps? Maybe something is just stuck.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly caused by the dreaded "[Secondary Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Secondary-Selection.html)." You likely did this by performing the command `M-Drag-mouse-1` (i.e. accidentally holding down `alt` while selecting text with the mouse).

One of the highlights (if you'll excuse the pun) of reading the Emacs manual was figuring out exactly what this was and (more importantly) how to get rid of it: `M-mouse-1` anywhere in any frame will clear the secondary selection overlay. Alternatively, [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8226) points out that running the function `(delete-overlay mouse-secondary-overlay)` will also clear the highlight.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like you have hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPC</kbd>. Thist stands for `set-mark-command`. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Need more context here.  The problem is emacs' paren matching/highlighting getting stuck on your embedded SQL query.  Why it's doing paren matching when it shouldn't probably depends on the major mode.  I'm assuming this is Python?  Can you provide more code context?

For now take a look at `M-x customize-option RET show-paren-style RET`.